# Which one do you prefer for Searching/Reporting DataTable or DTO or Domain Class?

Tags: datatable, domain-driven-design, dto

The project currently I am working in requires a lot of searhing/filtering pages. For example I have a comlex search page to get Issues by data,category,unit,...

Issue Domain Class is complex and contains lots of value objects and child objects.

.I am wondering how people deal with Searching/Filtering/Reporting for UI. As far As I know I have 3 options but none of them make me happier.

1.) Send parameters to Repository/DAO to Get DataTable and Bind DataTable to UI Controls.For Example to ASP.NET GridView

```
DataTable dataTable =issueReportRepository.FindBy(specs);
.....
grid.DataSource=dataTable;
grid.DataBind();
```

In this option I can simply by pass the Domain Layer and query database for given specs. And I dont have to get fully constructed complex Domain Object. No need for value objects,child objects,.. Get data to displayed in UI in DataTable directly from database and show in the UI.

But If have have to show a calculated field in UI like method return value I have to do this in the DataBase because I don't have fully domain object. I have to duplicate logic and DataTable problems like no intellisense etc...

2.)Send parameters to Repository/DAO to Get DTO and Bind DTO to UI Controls.

```
IList<IssueDTO> issueDTOs =issueReportRepository.FindBy(specs);
....
grid.DataSource=issueDTOs;
grid.DataBind();
```

In this option is same as like above but I have to create anemic DTO objects for every search page. Also For different Issue search pages I have to show different parts of the Issue Objects.IssueSearchDTO, CompanyIssueTO,MyIssueDTO....

3.) Send parameters to Real Repository class to get fully constructed Domain Objects.

```
IList<Issue> issues =issueRepository.FindBy(specs);
//Bind to grid...
```

I like Domain Driven Design and Patterns. There is no DTO or duplication logic in this option.but in this option I have to create lot's of child and value object that will not shown in the UI.Also it requires lot's ob join to get full domain object and performance cost for needles child objects and value objects.

I don't use any ORM tool Maybe I can implement Lazy Loading by hand for this version but It seems a bit overkill.

Which one do you prefer?Or Am I doing it wrong? Are there any suggestions or better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a few suggestions, but of course the overall answer is "it depends".

First, you should be using an ORM tool or you should have a very good reason not to be doing so.

Second, implementing Lazy Loading by hand is relatively simple so in the event that you're not going to use an ORM tool, you can simply create properties on your objects that say something like:

```
private Foo _foo;
public Foo Foo
{  
  get {  
         if(_foo == null)
         {
            _foo = _repository.Get(id);
         }
         return _foo;
       }
}
```

Third, performance is something that should be considered initially but should not drive you away from an elegant design.  I would argue that you should use (3) initially and only deviate from it if its performance is insufficient.  This results in writing the least amount of code and having the least duplication in your design.

If performance suffers you can address it easily in the UI layer using Caching and/or in your Domain layer using Lazy Loading.  If these both fail to provide acceptable performance, then you can fall back to a DTO approach where you only pass back a lightweight collection of value objects needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *great* question and I wanted to provide my answer as well. I think the *technically best* answer is to go with option #3. It provides the ability to best describe and organize the data along with scalability for future enhancements to reporting/searching requests.

*However* while this might be the overall best option, there is a huge cost IMO vs. the other (2) options which are the additional design time for all the classes and relationships needed to support the reporting needs (again under the premise that there is no ORM tool being used).

I struggle with this in a lot of my applications as well and the reality is that #2 is the best compromise between time and design. Now if you were asking about your busniess objects and all their needs there is **no** question that a fully laid out and properly designed model is important and there is no substitute. However when it comes to reporting and searching this to me is a different animal. #2 provides strongly typed data in the anemic classes and is not as primitive as hardcoded values in DataSets like #1, and still reduces greatly the amount of time needed to complete the design compared to #3.

Ideally I would love to extend my object model to encompass all reporting needs, but sometimes the effort required to do this is so extensive, that creating a separate set of classes just for reporting needs is an easier but still viable option. I actually asked almost this identical question a few years back and was also told that creating another set of classes (essentially DTOs) for reporting needs was not a bad option.

So to wrap it up, #3 is technically the best option, but #2 is probably the most realistic and viable option when considering time and quality together for complex reporting and searching needs.